# Long build times with sbt android-plugin

Tags: android, scala, sbt, sbt-android-plugin

I have created a demo application with the sbt android-plugin.

The app is very simple.
I have placed a `MainActivity.java` file under `/src/main/java/my/package/` and when a button is pressed it takes you to a second `Activity` but done in `Scala`.

Everything is working fine but the build times are killing me.
When I modify something I run in my device using:

> > android:package-debug
>
> > android:start-device

My issue is that it takes almost a complete minute to build a two activities project.
Is there another way to compile and run?

This is my output of android:package-debug

> > android:package-debug [info] Wrote
> /Users/macarse/Documents/demo/target/src_managed/main/scala/my/package/TR.scala
> [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to
> /Users/macarse/Documents/demo/target/scala-2.9.0-1/classes...
> ProGuard, version 4.6 ProGuard is released under the GNU General
> Public License. You therefore must ensure that programs that link to
> it (scala, ...) carry the GNU General Public License as well.
> Alternatively, you can apply for an exception with the author of
> ProGuard. Reading program directory
> [/Users/macarse/Documents/demo/target/scala-2.9.0-1/classes] Reading
> program jar
> [/Users/macarse/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.0-1/lib/scala-library.jar]
> (filtered) Reading library jar
> [/Users/macarse/Documents/android-sdk-mac_86/platforms/android-4/android.jar]
> Note: You're ignoring all warnings! Preparing output jar
> [/Users/macarse/Documents/demo/target/classes.min.jar]   Copying
> resources from program directory
> [/Users/macarse/Documents/demo/target/scala-2.9.0-1/classes]   Copying
> resources from program jar
> [/Users/macarse/.sbt/boot/scala-2.9.0-1/lib/scala-library.jar]
> (filtered) [info] Dexing
> /Users/macarse/Documents/demo/target/classes.dex [info] Packaging
> /Users/macarse/Documents/demo/target/demo-0.1.apk [success] Total
> time: 56 s, completed Oct 29, 2011 4:22:54 PM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

- [preinstall scala on the phone/emulator](http://zegoggl.es/2011/07/how-to-preinstall-scala-on-your-android-phone.html)
- [Include predexed scala as a library](https://github.com/scala-android-libs/scala-android-libs)

There is also a project called [treeshaker for Eclipse](http://code.google.com/p/treeshaker/) which is a lot faster than proguard, but it is not integrated w/ the sbt plugin yet.

Answer (score 3):

It takes long time because proguard need to process Scala standard library to minimize the .apk file you get, and Scala standard library is huge.

I will suggest you switch to Scala 2.8 if you didn't use features of Scala 2.9, because 2.8 has a smaller standard library.

In the other hand, don't use `android:package-debug` when not necessary. `compile` will compile your source code, it is sufficient if you only want to make sure your program could be compiled.

Only use `android:package-debug` when you are about to test it on the Android device, this will save your time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. AFAIK compile also does the proguard pass so it will take long time as well.

Comment: That is not correct, at least in android-plugin 0.6.x. `compile` will not do the proguard pass.